# php pdo category level access

Tags: php, pdo

i want category level access to users, i will give from admin side which categories users should access and which are not. Here i have trouble please help me, here is my code

In my database permission table there, in that userid and catids fields there so user if click on category function will see in permission table if user has permission are not then it will dipplay.

```
public function Grants($username)
{
$q = $this->db->prepare("select * from permissions where user = ?");
$q->bindParam(1, $username);
$q->execute();
$results = $q->fetchAll();
return $results;
}
```

**category page**

```
$check = new Access;
$data = $check->Grants($user);
foreach($data as $v)
{
if($v['catid'] == $_GET['p'])
{
foreach($nav as $list)
{
echo '<a href="subcat.php?p='. $list['id'] . '">' . '<li style="display:inline; padding:10px;">' . $list['catname'] . '</li>'  . '</a>';
}
}
else{
echo 'Access Denied'; }
}
```

if i had only one category in permission table it is working fine, if user had two or more catids not working.

Permission table example:
User>1 catid>1,2,3 array model giving problem how do i solve please help, if i place only one category it is working.

Comment: What does `print_r($data);` give you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is stored as I think it is from what you posted, it would look like this:

```
------------------------
|  User   |   catid    |
------------------------
    1         1,2,3
```

Am I right? If that is the case. Then when you call this:

```
$check = new Access;
$data = $check->Grants($user);
```

Your `$data` variable would contain something like this:

```
1,2,3
```

and **NOT** an array as you think it would.

What you should do is use [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to create that url:

```
$check = new Access;
$data = explode(',', $check->Grants($user));
```

Which, in turn; should give you an array like this:

```
Array (
    [0] => 1,
    [1] => 2,
    [2] => 3,
)
```

Allowing you to iterate as you require.

---

**EDIT**

As per your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24795483/php-pdo-category-level-access/24795622?noredirect=1#comment38485648_24795622), you need to access the `catid` array element. Provided you have the right php version, you could simple do this:

```
$check = new Access;
$data = explode(',', $check->Grants($user)[0]['catid']);
```

Or if that throws error, try this:

```
$check = new Access;
$cats = $check->Grants($user);
$data = explode(',', $cats[0]['catid']);
```

Comment: Yes you thought right for table data, but it is not working as per your change

Comment: warning message explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given

Comment: @user3164590 so what does `print_r($check->Grants($user));` give you?

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [0] => 1 [catid] => 1,2,3 [1] => 1,2,3 [user] => veeru [2] => veeru ) )

Comment: @user3164590 see edit :) (*Provided only one row is returned.*)

Comment: for second method output coming Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 ) like this

Comment: @user3164590 First method means PHP version too low to access it that way, second method is what you want to use!

Comment: Second Method Working Thank You. Acccess Denied running in loop how to stop. i had two categories in permission table when it was not there Access Denied Coming Twice even i had placed out side loop.

Comment: @user3164590 Just remove this from the `foreach` loop -> `else { echo 'Access Denied'; }`

Answer (score 0):

I have found simple solution for this.

```
$check = new Access;
$data = $check->Grants($user);

foreach($data as $result)
{
$str = $result['catid'];
$string = explode(',' , $str);
}
if(in_array($_GET['p'], $string))
{
foreach($nav as $list)
{
echo '<a href="subcat.php?p='. $list['id'] . '">' . '<li style="display:inline; padding:10px;">' . $list['catname'] . '</li>'  . '</a>';
}

}
else { echo "You dont have permission"; }
```